# How to make variable accessible only within its own method

Tags: python, variables

I still have a little bit of confusion around the subject of local and global scope, I want to make a method that runs while not done.

But I use this throughout other methods as well, so I can't make it just global.

Anyone have a suggestion how I can make this method work, without making it global?

This is the code:

```
def makeNavPlan(self, agent_location, destination=(0,0)):
    deltaX = agent_location[0] - destination[0]
    deltaY = agent_location[1] - destination[1]

    global navPlan
    navPlan = []

    done = False

    while not done:
        if(deltaX > 0):
            navPlan.append("Left")
            deltaX -= 1
        elif(deltaY > 0):
            navPlan.append("Up")
            deltaY -= 1
        else:
            done = True
            print navPlan
            return navPlan
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed one of the main points of classes, which is encapsulation. You can assign values as instance attributes on `self` and they will be available throughout in any method.

```
self.navPlan = []

self.done = False

while not self.done:
    if(deltaX > 0):
        self.navPlan.append("Left")
        deltaX -= 1
    elif(deltaY > 0):
        self.navPlan.append("Up")
        deltaY -= 1
    else:
        self.done = True
```

Comment: Thanks man, forgot to answer to you, But you're advice really helped me in understanding encapsulation and now I use it in a much more sophisticated way;) many thanks! Best wishes from holland!!